# Get all hdfs direcorties only no files

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

Is there a way to get all the hdfs directories not files ie if y hdfs structure is like below:

```
/user/classA/part-r-0000
/user/classA/part-r-0001
/user/classA/part-r-0002
/user/classA/_counter/val1
/user/classA/_counter/val2
/user/classA/_counter/val3
/user/classA/_counter/val4
/user/classB/part-r-0000
/user/classB/part-r-0001
/user/classB/_counter/val1
/user/classB/_counter/status/test_file1
```

Result should be

```
/user/classA/
/user/classA/_counter
/user/classB
/user/classB/_counter
/user/classB/_counter/status/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hdfs dfs -ls -R /user | grep "^d"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you wanted spark(added apache-spark tag) hadoop solution I think its more opt than just hdfs command

- logic is list all file status of hadoop filesystem using spark...

`isDirectory` will check dir or not based on that it filters.

```
    package examples

    import org.apache.log4j.Level
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

    object ListHDFSDirectories  extends  App{
      val logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org")
      logger.setLevel(Level.WARN)
      val spark = SparkSession.builder()
        .appName(this.getClass.getName)
        .config("spark.master", "local[*]").getOrCreate()

      val hdfspath = "." // your path here
      import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
      val fs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
      fs.listStatus(new Path(s"${hdfspath}")).filter(_.isDirectory).map(_.getPath).foreach(println)
    }
```

Result :

```
file:/Users/user/codebase/myproject/target
file:/Users/user/codebase/myproject/Rel
file:/Users/user/codebase/myproject/spark-warehouse
file:/Users/user/codebase/myproject/metastore_db
file:/Users/user/codebase/myproject/.idea
file:/Users/user/codebase/myproject/src
```

Comment: Why are you even using Spark for this? Outside of getting the config object, it's just plain Scala

Comment: @cricket : user mentioned spark tag + scala before your edit so as the solution given. in order to access the hadoop file system need `spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration` thats where spark comes in to picture. I thought some times between spark job we need to query the file system. Felt like OP wanted that kind of solution...